# How many pages were visited at least once in a time period (Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to measure how many pages in my website where visited at least once in a given time period using Google Analytics.

When I look at Behaviour-->Site Content-->All Pages, the column heading shows me how many page views in total. Is the number xxxxx in the bottom right next to the paging showing 1 to 10 of xxxxx the total number pages visited at least once? If not - where might I find that information? (If every pages on my site was visited once I suppose it should equate to the total number of unique URLS on the site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "xxxxx" is the number of unique pages of your site. Each row in the Behaviour > Site Content > All pages report corresponds to a different page that was viewed on your site. So if you want to see the pages that were viewed within a certain time period, that is where you would find it. You can adjust the time period in the upper right corner.